# How to handle "&" in Echo command

Tags: shell-script, echo, special-characters

I required to Echo following information but I am getting error.

```
echo Mumbai & Banglore
```

But I am getting error as follows,

```
'Banglore' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: The error message smells a bit like the windows command.com command line interface (esp. the mention of "batch files"). What system are you running exactly, and are you sure it's on topic on unix.SE?

Comment: The error message is exactly the text reported if the command as shown is run at a Windows CMD prompt

Comment: In a shell script, `&` is a statement separator: `A & B` means to start execution of A in the background and then immediately start B. In your case, you are running `echo Mumbai` in the background and then start `Bangalore`. It seems that you don't have in your PATH an executable named _Bangalore_. However, as roaima and ikkachu already explained, you are not running a unix shell script at all, so this is the wrong place to ask anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your command on this way to escape the ampersand:

```
echo Mumbai \& Banglore
```

or use single quotes

```
echo 'Mumbai & Banglore'
```

In case of use `cmd` (Windows) you can use caret:

```
echo Mumbai ^& Banglore
```

Comment: Thanks for feedback , but both options are tried but those are not working , if any other options are there then pls share

Comment: @Vips, both options work in `bash`. What is your shell?

Comment: And both work in `zsh`

Comment: @Vips, I add another option to escape `&`